# Mockito when() not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I have created a test case using Mockito.I want to test a controller.When the controller is called i want to send back a responce object and dont want the code inside controller to execute.But even though i have used when(functionName).thenReturn(), its getting into the controllers code.What am i doing wrong here?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MockitoController {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

protected MockMvc mockMvc;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Before
public void setup() {

    MyController myController = Mockito.mock(myController.class);

    ResponseView jsonResponse = new ResponseView();
    jsonResponse.setStatus(1);
    jsonResponse.setMessage("true");

    Mockito.when((myController.deleteMedia(Mockito.anyInt()))).thenReturn(jsonResponse);

    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();

}

@Test
public void deleteMediaMockito() throws Exception {

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/library/99")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());

    assertEquals(1, jsonObject.get("status"));
}
}
```

Comment: Either I'm blind or you're just creating `myController` to use it in 'when'. When exactly should the tested class use the Mock it doesn't know?

Comment: Yeah, how and where do you inject the `myController` mock? Because apart from your setup method it is not used anywhere. Maybe you meant to use it with you `mockMvc` class, in which case you will have to set it's controller to be your mock.

Comment: Mockito.when((myController.deleteMedia(Mockito.anyInt()))).thenReturn(jsonResponse); here i have injected myController.Its going inside the method "deleteMedia" which handles the delete API

Comment: @VallabhLakade no, that is where you setup your mock controller to return the correct response. As neither the `RequestBuilder` or the `mockMvc` are aware if it (you haven't set it in either one of them) the mock is not used when their code is executed.

Answer (score 2):

I would try a local class containing your mock controller. Something like this inside your test class. This will register your mock and overwrite the real MyController inside the application context.

```
@Configuration
    public static class MyMockConfig {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        MyController myController() {
            Mockito.mock(MyController.class);
        }
    }
```

But I am not convinced that the thing you are testing makes sense. MockMvc is used to test your controller as a whole including the requestMappings etc.

So why would you mock parts of it. The controller is your unit under test. Try to mock away its dependencies.

But still - the code I posted can help to inject mocks into spring beans.

Comment: I used mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(mediaLibraryController).build(); and it worked.But i dont know why it was not working with webAppContextSetup.I searched for standaloneSetup's description but didnt understand it

Comment: the standaloneSetup does not use the full application context and you can explicitly pass your controller instances. The webAppContextSetup uses the application context and takes the MyController instance from your application context rather than your mock. So at runtime your mock is never touched.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Mockito.anyInt() method for a constant here:

```
Mockito.when((myController.deleteMedia(Mockito.anyInt()))).thenReturn(jsonResponse);
```

This method should be used for matching purposes, not to provide values. I had a situation similar to yours, the tests/whens were behaving really strange, and began doing what I was expecting to only after I replace them for constants.

I hope it helps!